# How to disable all Child Elements of View to capture mouse touch event

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to Horizontal Slider Menu in Android(like Facebook).

I want only my container View to be able to capture mouse touch event.

I have tried `setEnable(false)` all of child elements of my container view. But It cause the view not to capture touch event.

```
public void ChangeMenuVisibility() {
        int menuWidth = menu.getMeasuredWidth();
        // Ensure menu is visible
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        int left = !menuOut ? 0 : menuWidth;
        container.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);
        menuOut = !menuOut;
        ViewUtils.enableDisableViewGroup(
                (ViewGroup) window.findViewById(R.id.main_content), !menuOut);
        window.findViewById(R.id.main_content).setEnabled(true);
    }
[ViewUtils.java]
    public static void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup,
            boolean enabled) {
        int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            view.setEnabled(enabled);
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```

What strategy should I follow to accomplish this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `View.onInterceptTouchEvent()` in the `ViewGroup`, don't call `super.onInterceptTouchEvent()` and return true. This causes the touch events to not be passed down the hierarchy (to the children of the `ViewGroup`).

Comment: It does'nt work. I extend Linear Layout and implement dispatchtouch event and return true. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem the inspiration of  @nmw's answer.

You should extend your View group (I prefer to use `LinearLayout`).

For the child elements  neglect the mouse touch event. You have to implement `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

This is example layout for solving this problem:

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    boolean mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent = true;

    /**
     * @return the mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent
     */
    public boolean ChildCanCaptureTouchEvent() {
        return mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent;
    }

    /**
     * @param mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent
     *            the mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent to set
     */
    public void ChildCanCaptureTouchEvent(boolean mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent) {
        this.mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent = mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!mChildCanCaptureTouchEvent)
            return true;

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont need to remove because I would pick your answer as true. I just wrote this for an example demonstration...