# Android: addview()- adding a new view on top of activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have the following layout with an imageview and textfield,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a01" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout will be transparent and I want to call this layout on top of a particular activity ,when the particular activity first starts, how to implement it with `addview()`?

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76529993/add-view-to-android-rootview-application-without-permission

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you want to show it:

```
FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View.inflate(this, R.layout.overlay_layout, rootLayout);
```

Then when you want to remove it:

```
FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
rootLayout.removeViewAt(rootLayout.getChildCount()-1);
```

That's a concise solution, you should remove the `View` by giving the `RelativeLayout` an id in the XML file, then remove by: `rootLayout.removeView(findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_relative_layout));`.

Comment: getting error at this line   View.inflate(this, R.layout.overlay_layout. rootLayout);

Comment: Change 'overlay_layout' to whatever you've named the layout that you posted.

Comment: i did..error saying  R.layout.quicktip doesn't have a field rootlayout

Comment: Ah, there was a typo - typed '.' instead of ',' - now fixed.

Comment: FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View.inflate(this, R.layout.overlay_layout, rootLayout);  this worked

Comment: how to remove layout view when cancel button in the same layout is clicked

Comment: Set an onClickListener (google 'view setonclicklistener') on your cancel button, then put the second part of the code I listed inside onClick().

Comment: i did that ..thanks...can u suggest how i can disable calling activity layout untill the my trasparent layout is on top?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, post another question with more detail.

Comment: now when my trasparent layout is on top of the activityA, the actual layout of the activityA is still functional, how to diable it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181394/how-to-disable-all-child-elements-of-view-to-capture-mouse-touch-event. If you don't understand how to do what that post explains, then ask another question.

Comment: @nmw Have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76529993/add-view-to-android-rootview-application-without-permission

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code to add the view.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

// fill in any details dynamically here
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
textView.setText("your text");

// insert into main view
View insertPoint =(View) findViewById(R.id.insert_point); // edited. 
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: @itsrajesh..   what is this line View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.insert_point);??

Comment: thats the view which you have to add the layout(any layout file) ..for example - this is your new activity layout . there only you are going to add something.. from another xml file. that may be linear layout or relative layout etc...

Comment: i didn't get your, what will be R.id.insert_point ,in my context?

Comment: see now the edited answer View insertPoint =(View) findViewById(R.id.insert_point); // edited.

Comment: that your layout id.. to which layout (view ) you are going to add.

Comment: you mean layout id of calling acitivity or the transparent layout?

Comment: you want to show like popup right ??? or want to add some other formats?? else show this transparent layout as the another Activity and show as on top of your needed activity.

Comment: else provide us the code.. which you are using to show the transparent activity.

Comment: how to call my activity on top of a other activity , when that other activity loads ?

Comment: from your activity on create pass the intent to transparent activity.. so it will look like being in top of your current activity.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of your calling activity should be inside FrameLayout (as in this layout last view added will be always on top of previous view ) ,
in onCreate method of calling activity inflate the given layout using LayoutInflater and use addView method of activity directly.

Comment: my calling activity dont have framelayout, without framelayourt can i use?

Comment: You can put a FramLayout in calling activity xml file (topmost node ) , as you need to put new view on top of current activity otherwise it will be added  after last view .