# Show custom view in all activities

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to show a view that should be shown in all activities. I don't know how to inherit views in android. What i did is below, its showing the view in first activity but not in all activities. This pease of code is form my BaseActivity, please help

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_error, null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

addContentView(child, params);
```

Comment: i dont think so . you can do this. because every activity runs alone and in its own separate thread.but you can animate your view like its come from previous activity.

Comment: Make use of `include` tag in xml

Answer (score 1):

You could get an Android specific `View` in the `Activity`. For example the following code below will add a `TextView` to the `Activity`'s content area.

```
    TextView tvSample = new TextView(this);
    tvSample.setText("Hello!");
    ((ViewGroup) hostActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(this);
```

Whereby `hostActivity` is your current `Activity` and `android.R.id.content` is a specific element (the content area, not including the `ActionBar`).

Alternatively, as already stated, make use of `<merge>` and `<include>` tags in your layout XMLs.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually i can not use <merge> and <include> because i have listener with some condition to show this view, and i want if i change the activity this view should not hide like toast in android.

Comment: If that is the case, you could place this code in your `BaseActivity`'s `setContentView` (but make sure to call `super.setContentView` on it), so that every time it opens an `Activity` (extending `BaseActivity`) will apply the code changes.

Comment: Yes i did it, but then it do not set content view of child

Comment: Sorry didn't get that. 
It would be something like, 
`public void setContentView(int resourceId) { 
 super.setContentView(resourceId); 
 // then the code above
}
`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with two solution 
for programmatically 
1)After adding child view to you parent View need to call setContentView(parentView) and pass you parent layout to it.
and With XMl 
2) You can use include tag. follow this link will help you.
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'include' tag of xml? It will do the job.

```
 <include
 android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_above=...
 android:layout_toLeftOf=...
 layout="@layout/header_logo_lyt" //Name of the xml layout file you want to include
 />
```

In the layout/xxxx use the name of your layout file that should be repeated.

After use the above code in your xml file like any other widget.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show it:

```
FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View.inflate(this, R.layout.overlay_layout, rootLayout);
```

Then when you want to remove it:

```
FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
rootLayout.removeViewAt(rootLayout.getChildCount()-1);
```

That's a concise solution, you should remove the `View` by giving the `RelativeLayout` an id in the XML file, then remove by: `rootLayout.removeView(findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_relative_layout));`.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195536/1708390) by [nmw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696420/nmw)